# What is this menu bar icon with three connected dots and a down arrow?

Tags: icon, menu-bar

[image]

It doesn't respond to clicks or right clicks.  I don't recall when it first appeared.

I'm running 10.11.6 El Capitan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LibreOffice update icon.

Googling the image led me to [MacRumours Forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-is-this-status-menu-icon.1940777/)

> It is the LibreOffice update dialog box that triggers this. Clicking
>   that icon opens the LibreOffice update dialog box, but it does not put
>   it in front of other applications. That is what is leading to
>   everyone's confusion about this icon.
>
> To verify, I closed the update dialog, put LibreOffice in front of my
>   other windows, and clicked the icon. The update dialog appears again.